# How to install CLISP under OS X El Capitan (10.11)?

Tags: macos

I want to install [CLISP](http://www.clisp.org/) to run some lisp programs. I am used to install it via

```
brew install clisp
```

**But I'm getting this error message:**

```
Error: libsigsegv 2.10 did not build
```

Is this due to the new [System Integrity Protection](http://www.amsys.co.uk/2015/06/el-capitan-system-integrity-protection/)? The log files are telling me this:

```
checking whether we are cross compiling... configure: error: in `/private/tmp/libsigsegv20150926-26734-xxczr8/libsigsegv-2.10':
configure: error: cannot run C compiled programs.
If you meant to cross compile, use `--host'.
See `config.log' for more details
```

**And the config.log:**

```
configure:3294: clang -o conftest    conftest.c  >&5
clang: warning: no such sysroot directory: ''
conftest.c:11:10: fatal error: 'stdio.h' file not found
#include <stdio.h>
         ^
```

> How can I run my LISP programs or, better, CLISP on OS X 10.11?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was an outdated XCode version. I had XCode 6.4 installed, **but for El Capitan, Version 7 is needed**.

[See here.](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/issues/42919)

So, for future readers:

> 1. Update XCode to version 7 via App Store (or Apple Developer website)
> 2. `brew install` works again like charm